# Laravel pass a value to a method via the route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have:

```
Route::delete('admin/sanitise/{id}/delete', ['as' => 'admin.sanitise.delete', 'uses' => 'ProductController@delete']);
```

With:

```
public function delete($id, $hard = false) {
    $product= Product::find($id);
    if($hard) {
        $product->destroy();
    } else {
        $product->delete();
    }
}
```

This lets both non-admins and admins delete products, but, I only want admins to be able to hard delete.

The route above is only accessible to admins.

What do I need to put in the route to set $hard to true?

Comment: Add it as an optional param http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#parameters-optional-parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would do something like this:

```
Route::delete('admin/sanitise/{id}/delete/{hard?}', ['as' => 'admin.sanitise.delete', 'uses' => 'ProductController@delete']);
```

The question mark in `{hard?}` tells laravel that this is an optional route parameter.

When you use this route somewhere, you'd set the params array like

```
$url = route('admin.sanitise.delete', ['id' => $someId, 'hard' => true]);
```

If you don't set the 'hard' key in the parameters for the route, the default `false` from your function definition will be used.